# How to avoid resource collisions in library jars?

Tags: java, maven, package, dependency-management

I'm worried about the situation when libraries `Foo` and `Bar` each expose a resource on the classpath with the same name, say `properties.txt` in this example.

Assuming a Maven set up and the `jars` are deployed with Maven, if I have this set up:

Library Foo:

```
$ cat Foo/src/main/resources/properties.txt
$ Foo
```

and Library Bar:

```
$ cat Bar/src/main/resources/properties.txt
$ Bar
```

And an `App` that depends on them, whose `pom` looks something like this - in a nutshell this just says "build a jar-with-dependencies, and depend on `Foo` and `Bar`:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>bundle-project-sources</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>single</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
            <mainClass>me.unroll.deptest.App</mainClass>
            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
          </manifest>
          <manifestEntries>
            <Implementation-Build>${buildNumber}</Implementation-Build>
          </manifestEntries>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
          <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Problem is it really seems like the `properties.txt` file was clobbered.  Let's try a `jar tf`:

```
unrollme-dev-dan:target Dan$ jar tf App-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar 
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
properties.txt
META-INF/maven/
META-INF/maven/me.unroll.deptest/
META-INF/maven/me.unroll.deptest/Bar/
META-INF/maven/me.unroll.deptest/Bar/pom.xml
META-INF/maven/me.unroll.deptest/Bar/pom.properties
META-INF/maven/me.unroll.deptest/Foo/
META-INF/maven/me.unroll.deptest/Foo/pom.xml
META-INF/maven/me.unroll.deptest/Foo/pom.properties
me/
me/unroll/
me/unroll/deptest/
me/unroll/deptest/App.class
```

So I ran a `main` class in `App` that does:

```
try (InputStream is = App.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("properties.txt")) {

    java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner(is);
        System.out.println("Scanner: " + s.next());

}
```

And the output is:

```
unrollme-dev-dan:target Dan$ java -jar App-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar 
Scanner: Bar
```

Whoops, Bar won.  No warnings or errors when `mvn package`-ing `App`.  No warnings or errors when running that the wrong file may have been chosen, in fact it failed silently.

So I want to ask proper practice to avoid this.  One, something like this should fail loudly, not softly.  Two, the only solution I can think is that all resource files should be properly packaged like everything else in Java development, i.e., a library should never expose `properties.txt` in the "global" namespace; it should appear in a folder like `me/unroll/deptest/foo` just like everything else.  I'm skeptical because I haven't seen any Maven example that actually does this.  So what is best practice here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And what do you do in *Java* to avoid collisions between libraries? Packages! This is established and well understood approach. Packages work with resources as well:

```
com/example/foo/Foo.class
com/example/foo/properties.txt
```

and second library:

```
com/example/bar/Bar.class
com/example/bar/properties.txt
```

Note that `properties.txt` lies in different packages and thus directories in final JAR. Actually this approach is preferred because the API for retrieving such resources becomes easier:

```
App.class.getResourceAsStream("properties.txt"))
```

vs.

```
Bar.class.getResourceAsStream("properties.txt"))
```

It just works because `Class.getResourceAsStream()` is by default local to package of underlying class. Of course when you are inside an instance method of either `Foo` or `Bar` you simply say `getClass().getResourceAsStream("properties.txt")`. Moreover you can still reference both files easily, just like you reference classes:

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("/com/example/foo/properties.txt");
getClass().getResourceAsStream("/com/example/bar/properties.txt");
```

---

> I'm skeptical because I haven't seen any Maven example that actually does this.

Real world example: you have a Spring integration test named `com.example.foo.FooTest`. By default Spring expects the context file to reside under: `/src/test/resources/com/example/foo/FooTest-context.xml`.

Comment: So note that my design involves package `App` retrieving a resource in package `Bar`.  So would actually have to call `App.class.getResourceAsStream("/me/unroll/bar/properties.txt")` if namespaced this way, or `App.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("me/unroll/bar/properties.txt")`.  Is this correct / good practice?

Comment: @djechlin: there is nothing wrong with that, just like you have to import `Bar` in `App`. BTW you don't need `getClassLoader()`, simply prepend `/` to use absolute paths.

Comment: How do you resolve resource conflicts for files that are in `META-INF`, such as `META-INF/services` where more than one dependency provides its own implementation of the same service?

Answer (score 2):

To complete the @Tomasz's answer with the maven code to do that :

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <targetPath>com/example/bar/</targetPath>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```