# Read files from different Jars in java

Tags: java, jar

I want to get values from properties file inside JARs. I have two Jar files. both of them in class-path.

1- lib/seed.jar  (has common.properties).

2- lib/span.jar  (has common.properties).

Both Jars has same name of properties file but with different value

When I use the following:

```
InputStream input = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/common.properties");
```

It will read only from the first jar, but I will be unable to read value from the second jar. How to let my code be able to access the file in those jar?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid resource collisions in library jars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14942323/how-to-avoid-resource-collisions-in-library-jars)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach will be effective,use the `getResources` method,like:

```
Enumeration<URL> resources = Main.class.getClassLoader().getResources("client.xml");
    while (resources.hasMoreElements()){
        URL url = resources.nextElement();
        File file = new File(url.getFile());
        FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
        System.out.println(input);
    }
```

And pay attention to the argument of the `getResources` is not be necessary start with `/`,if not,the method will not get correct file.